# django query get extra data with annotate

Tags: django, django-models, group-by, orm, django-orm

Assuming it is a system with user's balance and there is a model `Record` to record balance history

```
class Record(models.Model):
  ...
  created_at = models.DatetimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  previous_value = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  value_change = models.IntegerField()
  '''
```

And then the list view is like

[image]

Now it's required to have options to make it group by day, as:

[image]

The question is: How to get the Final Balance of the Day?

Current Code is only providing the change but not the balance.

```
qs = Record.objects.order_by('-created_at').values('created_at__date').annotate(day_change=Sum('change'))
```

Comment: Where do you store the `balance` in the model? Or is it calculated as `previous_value + value_change`?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat it is calculated. Let me know if the approach is bad